# Java storing data

Tags: java, maps

I am developing a simple hydrologic model that will contain many subwatersheds (end product will contain at least 10 different subwatersheds). Each subwatershed is described by the same parameters, but the parameters have different values for each subwatershed.

So for instance, subwatershed A is described be these properties and their corresponding values:

```
Double subA_Impervious = 0.3;
Double subA_Pervious = 0.7;
Double[] subA_CNs = {55.0, 85.0, 92.0};
```

subwatershed B is described by the same properties but has different values:

```
Double subB_Impervious = 0.4;
Double subB_Pervious = 0.6;
Double[] subB_CNs = {50.0, 70.0, 82.0};
```

Some properties are described by arrays, but most are just Double.
Each subwatershed is described by many properties (I just showed 3 for an example, but there are at least 15 different properties).

My question is, what is the best way to store this data knowing that I will have at minimum 10 different subwatersheds? This data will be accessed in the main program ...and input into other objects that make various calculations. 
Should I create a generic class with getters/setters that is then instantiated 10 times within the main program (1 object per subbasin), or have some sort of class create map objects (1 map object per subbasin) for the main class (this second method makes most sense to me), or have one class store all the parameters for all the subbasins (1 instantiated object in the main program)? Not sure how I would set up the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's an object-oriented language.  Create a class that encapsulates the data and behavior into a single software component.  Create one for each instance you need.

You are thinking about it incorrectly if you're stuck on primitives, strings, and collections.  Think objects.

> Should I create a generic class with getters/setters that is then
>   instantiated 10 times within the main program (1 object per subbasin),

Don't just make that object a carrier with getters and setters.  The worst thing you can do is pull the data out and do calculations.

Better to encapsulate those calculations inside the object.  Let it perform them and ask for the outcomes.  Changing state means redoing the calculations.

```
package model;

public class Watershed {
   // better to work with primitives for calculations.
   private double impervious;
   private double pervious;
   private double [] cn; // what's this?

   // lots more to add here.
}
```

Comment: Okay, I guess I was thinking to much about the topic. I already do have a subbasin class built. For some reason, I was thinking it would be good to have all model data and parameters stored elsewhere. I'm just learning java (migrating from python where I do mostly scientific programming, so not familiar with OOP). Is there ever a time where it is appropriate to store data for a program outside of the class that uses that data, or is it ever appropriate to generate a class that stores data with get and set methods, but does not do any calculations with that data (serves as kind of a database)?

Comment: Python is a hybrid: functional and object-oriented.  You use the functional side more with NumPy and SciPy.  Anything can be done.  You already know that not using objects works fine from your experience with Python.  There's no OO traffic cop to take away your IDE.  You'll discover the consequences of your choices as you continue to use and develop your system.  If it's hard to use and extend, it's time to rethink it.  If everything seems easy, especially six months later, then you've done a good job.